# how to retrieve User model with only one row of Details model (User: One -> Details: Many), based on MAX of date - Laravel 8.0

Tags: mysql, eloquent, relationship

I have `User` model and `Detail` model in this relation:
`public function hmdetails(){return $this->hasMany ('App\Models\Detail','fk_user_id','id');}` Table `details` contain field *starting_from* which describes the starting date of the employee's position.

I need to extract Users::which are not former employees WITH current, last Details:: (MAX of starting_from)

My best approach doesn't work:

```
$former_employees = Position::select('id')->where('is_active', 0)->orWhere('is_active', 2)->pluck('id');
$activeusers = User::with('hmdetails')->where('fk_firm_id', auth()->user()->fk_firm_id)

        ->whereDoesntHave('hmdetails', function($q) use ($former_employees) {$q->whereIn('fk_position_id', $former_employees)->where ('starting_from', '<', now());})

        ->whereHas('hmdetails', function($q){$q->max('starting_from');})

        ->orderBy('name')->get()->groupBy('software_required');
```

I receive the message, which is hard to understand for me: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select max(starting_from) as aggregate from details where users.id = details.fk_user_id)

However,  if I delete `->whereHas('hmdetails', function($q){$q->max('starting_from');})` - it **almost** works... I get my proper users, however without current details.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql